# add LIstener on OS in JAVA

Tags: java

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Robot bot = new Robot();
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
  bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
}
});
```

I wrote program in Java when I click on JFrame, it will press SHIFT key automatically. But I don't want exactly this program.
I want that when I click on Desktop or anywhere of O.S. (not only JFrame), it execute that command. 
Is there any way to do this? Please help me. Appreciate in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use JNI to do this.

An approach to do this on Windows is given in this blog entry http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't have any information about JNI. That's why i coludn't getany useful information from that link. :( Where can i read or learn that what is JNI? ( it can be book or any site) i need your advise

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/ should help you get started with JNI